# Frames and TFs are disappearing

Tags: ros, librviz, 3d-visualization, learning-tf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two robot models. The first robot is the vehicle (AR.Drone) and the second is the Phantom Omni Device. I use rviz for visualization. I have problem with the tree of the TFs. Now for the AR.Drone, the parent  frame is the 'world' frame while the parent frame for the Phantom Omni is the base frame. Now there are two problems. The first one is that when the TFs are shown in Rviz, the world frame appear for 3 seconds and starts to disappear. The second problem, the base TF is not shown. I want both robots to be shown with their URDF files but RViz only allow us to choose one Fixed frame.. What should I do ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191054/frames-and-tfs-are-disappearing/) by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2014-08-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In RViz, go the the TF tree drop-down menu and increase the timeout time.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2014-10-09**:
This solves my first problem.
It worked! Thanks but I really would like to know from where I should specify the time line in the code or the launch file ??

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-10-09**:
You can save your rviz config and load it from a launch file.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From your description, it appears you have two separate tf trees, one for the ar drone and other for the phantom.

Have you visualised the tree to see what is happening? You can do so by running (see [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf)):

```
rosrun tf view_frames
evince frames.pdf
```

You will probably see that you have two separate trees, and there is no connection to traverse from one tree to another.

You could broadcast a static transform between `world` and `base_frame` to connect both trees. [This page](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher) shows you how to do it.

I hope I'm not too far off your problem.

---

Originally posted by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) with karma: 806 on 2014-08-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2014-10-09**:
I didnt try it yet but this solves the second problem.